# How to update a column with accumulated total of another column in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

I have a table like this:

```
COL1 | COL2
------------
1    | NULL
2    | NULL
3    | NULL
4    | NULL
```

How can I use SQL to update the COL2 which has the accumulated total of all previous row? Like this:

```
COL1 | COL2
------------
1    | 1
2    | 3
3    | 6
4    | 10
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from my colleague: (Assume the table name is abc)

UPDATE abc set col2 = (
    SELECT temp.t from (SELECT abc.id, SUM(def.col1) as t FROM `abc` join abc as def on def.id<=abc.id group by abc.id)as  temp WHERE abc.id=temp.id 
)

Or we can use this:

REPLACE INTO abc SELECT abc.id,r2.col1, SUM(r2.col1) as col2 FROM abc join abc as r2 on r2.id<=abc.id group by abc.id